# updated bcmwl-kernel-source : wifi no longer exists (wired network doesnt even show up)

Tags: wifi, laptop

Completely clean install of Odin. Wifi worked, but figured if there is an update, should get it. Updated bcmwl-kernel-source. Wifi no longer visible
I tried un-installing bcmwl, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linux Kernel Headers install process outlined on Github / elementary
/ appcenter: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1603#issue-965454894

Edit: this process worked for me until restarting the computer. On restart wi-fi is no longer visible in network settings.

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, in the mean time, since it was a clean install, i just installed it again but didn't update the bcmwl this time.

Comment: I'm running a clean install too, I'll try wiping and installing again